# Https call giving exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

My code is like

```
encodestring = "test@gmail.com:test"
enc = Base64.encode64(encodestring)
auth = "Basic #{enc}"

https = Net::HTTP.new('localhost',  443)
https.use_ssl = true
path = '/user/test'
query_string = "#{auth}"

https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # don't display warnings
resp = https.post(path,query_string)
```

here test is a method inside user_controller.rb file.If i am making simple http request its working fine but while making https request it is giving exception "SocketError (initialize: name or service not known)".Please help me to make it a valid https call. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples I've seen have taken a *host name* as the first argument to `HTTP.new`, rather than a URL. Try this:

```
https = Net::HTTP.new('localhost',  443)
```

It's not clear whether you actually want to connect to port 443 or 3001 - you obviously can't connect to both. If you want 3001, replace the 443 above.

Comment: I changed my code and giving host name as first argument and 443 as port name . but now it is giving another exception "org.jruby.Ruby.getSelectorPool()Lorg/jruby/util/io/SelectorPool;"

Comment: @PpM: That's not a very full exception - is there no useful *message* there?

Comment: Actually i am getting 2 exceptions and they are
 
1.Java::JavaLang::NoSuchMethodError (org.jruby.Ruby.getSelectorPool()Lorg/jruby/util/io/SelectorPool;):

2.ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `clean_message' for #<Java::JavaLang::NoSuchMethodError:0x9384fb>) in C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9.1/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.8/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:

Comment: @PpM: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498568/savon-jruby-1-5-1-selectorpool-javalang-error) suggests that upgrading to JRuby 1.5.6 may solve your problem.

Comment: But mine is the latest one JRuby 1.6.4

Comment: @PpM: I don't think you're actually *using* 1.6.4 - look at the filename: "C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9.1/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/..." - perhaps the problem is that you've separately installed 1.6.4 but NetBeans is using its own version?